# Merging multiple excel sheets based on different column values in R

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse

I'm a bit new to R so apologies up front if its not explained as clear as it should be. I have 6 excel sheets within a single workbook (Trees_2020, Trees_2017, Trees_2014, Trees_2011, Trees_2008, Trees_2003). These contain plot IDs (ID_Plot), within plot tree ID numbers (ID_tree) and then growth data (DBH_mm). The problem is the tree IDs do not remain the same through the years but are linked based on their old ID (Field_Mapping software recognises them based on location but assigns a new number which is linked to the Old_ID).
What I'm trying to do is merge all the sheets linking the years together based on the plot ID and then the Old_ID to current ID.

[2020 Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzLTY.jpg)

[2017 Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WfLA.jpg)

You can see in the 2020 sheet a column linking to the Old_ID number of 2017 and this is true of all sheets. Trees that are recorded for the first time do not have an Old_ID number in that first recording.

The ideal output would be a single sheet where a unique identifier is added for each tree, the DBH of each tree for each year linked together based on the plot_ID and the within plot ID_tree (coupled based on Old_ID)

[Ideal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkwAp.jpg)

Apologies if thats very confusing but I struggled to explain it in a simpler way. I've been playing with tidyverse and loops but can't seem to figure it out so any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you share the original xlsx-file?

Comment: No there is no option to upload the file

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.